# How to count changes in a column

Tags: r, counter

I am searching for a simple way to count changes occurring in a column "AA" of my data frame; so the new column "BB" should look like in the df given below:

`df <- as.data.frame(cbind("Year"=c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003), "AA"=c(136,137,137,158,162,21,21,55,55,55), "BB"=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6)))`

In other words, any change (increase or decrease) in "AA" should be accounted for in "BB" by adding up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `rle` for this:

```
foo <- rle(df$AA)
foo$values <- 1:length(foo$values)
df$BB <- inverse.rle(foo)
```

Comment: Great - inverse.rle() was the thing I was missing - many thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I think @Roland may have the fastest answer.  However, I often find it difficult to see what I was doing when I've written code that way in the past.

Comment: Both versions are so fast that the difference shouldn't matter for most applications.

Comment: Two of my favorite toys ( rle & 1/rle )

Answer (score 6):

I prefer using `cumsum` like this:

```
df$BB <-  cumsum(c(1, head(df$AA, -1) != tail(df$AA, -1)))
```

Benchmarks with `x <- sample(1:10,1e4,TRUE)`:

```
Unit: microseconds
   expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
 Jus(x) 1259 1330   1936 1987 5289   100
 Rol(x)  391  402    463  616 3903   100
```